# Starting Outlook and having an email pre-populated from command line

Tags: command-line, outlook

Is this possible?  I want to have the To:, Body, and an Attachment all pre-populated so all the user has to do is click send.  Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Open a new mail message (`ipm.note` is the [message class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/en-en/library/office/ff861573.aspx) for emails)

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note
```

Open a new mail message and populate sender:

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m someone@microsoft.com
```

Open a new mail message with attachment:

```
 outlook.exe /c ipm.note /a filename
```

Combination: (First one below didn't work in Office 2016, second did)

```
 outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m someone@microsoft.com&subject=test%20subject&body=test%20body
 outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "someone@microsoft.com&subject=test%20subject&body=test%20body"
```

The %20 has to be used to produce a blank space.

- More details at [Command Line for Creating a Pre-Addressed E-mail Message](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/287573/how-to-use-command-line-switches-to-create-a-pre-addressed-e-mail-message-in-outlook)
- Command-line switches can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Command-line-switches-for-Outlook-for-Windows-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6)

This works for instance with a classic Outlook 2016 (build 16.0.4849.1000).

But, as [Snozzlebert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2294031/snozzlebert) notes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248569/starting-outlook-and-having-an-email-pre-populated-from-command-line/248598#comment106314209_248598), for a  Outlook 365 Version 2001 (Build 12430.20184) the syntax would be:

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "someone@microsoft.com?subject=test"
```

> the culprit was the `&` after the email-address - replacing it with `?` solved the problem.
>   It seems that Microsoft changed the syntax to the HTML mailto syntax.

Comment: Neat. The command-line is having a renaissance at Microsoft, it seems.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that - and I probably never would have tried.

Comment: Awesome!  But it doesn't allow you to attach a file AND fill in the To/Body of the email.  Try it out.  It doesn't work.  Also, the value of the /m parameter should be surrounded with quotes.  I had to do that to get it to work because apparently the & means something to the shell interpreter.  TY!

Comment: You are correct. It seem command-line can only get you so far...

Comment: @VonC What if we want it to send right out without having to click send.

Comment: @Mowgli not sure, actually. It could be the base for a new question.

Comment: @VonC sorry to ask question in existing topic, but I tried searching for this whole day yesterday and couldn't find solution only this post closely related and you look like most experienced with 285k so I asked. I'll still start another new question in outlook and cmd section Thanks.

Comment: @Mowgli I understand, and you did well asking it here first, but (since I don't have an immediate answer) a separate question (with a link back to this one) will be more effective.

Comment: Can anybody confirm if this still works with Outlook Version 2001 (Build 12430.20184)?

The subject line is empty if I use the following command: `outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "someone@microsoft.com&subject=test"`

Comment: @Snozzlebert 11+ years later (after writing this answer), I just tested it, with an Outlook 2016 at work (build 16.0.4849.1000). It does work (still). I don't know for version 2001.

Comment: @VonC Thank you for testing. I seem to have Outlook 365 Version 2001 (In Outlook under `File > Office Account > About Outlook` it just states Version 2001).
The reason I'm asking is because a user has reported a problem and now I have the same problem (it worked a few days ago).
Anyway the problem is fixed now - **the culprit was the `&` after the email-address - replacing it with `?` solved the problem** - e.g. `outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "someone@microsoft.com?subject=test"`. It seems that Microsoft changed the syntax to the HTML mailto syntax.

Comment: @Snozzlebert Thank you. I have edited the answer to include your comment for more visibility.

Answer (score 9):

You can attach files AND pre-fill in the To/Body if you simply place " " quotes around the command after the `/m`

Example:

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "someone@microsoft.com&subject=test%20subject&body=test%20body" /a test.txt
```

Comment: +1 yeah it is just the quotes, no need complex stuff

Answer (score 3):

VonC's solution works, but as stated in the comments by skbergam it doesn't allow for attachments.

If, like me, that's a biggie then the following WSH code does it.

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMsg = olApp.CreateItem(0)

With olMsg
  .To = "test@testing.com"
  '.CC = "cc@testing.com"
  '.BCC = "bcc@testing.com"
  .Subject = "Subject"
  .Body = "Body"
  .Attachments.Add "C:\path\to\attachment\test.txt" 

  .Display
End With
```

I've tried it with Outlook2003