# How to format the outlook email pre-populated from command line

Tags: command-line, outlook

I've been using following command to pre-populate my emails from windows command line, that's exactly what I wanna, the only thing I still cannot figure out is how to add simple html format to the email body, I tried add < b > < /b > for instance, but it didn't work, I just wanna some simple ones, like bold text, text coloring, nothing fancy, thanks

> outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m someone@microsoft.com&subject=test%20subject&body=test%20body

reference:
[Starting Outlook and having an email pre-populated from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248569/starting-outlook-and-having-an-email-pre-populated-from-command-line)
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;181991