# Need to open ms outlook with attachments

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mailto

I need to implement the below logic using java.

--> When i click on a button, MS Outlook need to get opened with To,CC,Subject and attachment.

We can use mailto for doing this but we can't add attachment if we use mailto.

i need to add multiple attachment from a shared folder to MS outlook

Please help me.

Using switched it is possible to have single attachment but i need to open outlook with 2+ attachment and send button should be available so that user can send the mail

Comment: Why use Outlook at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248569/starting-outlook-and-having-an-email-pre-populated-from-command-line

Comment: @stefan - user need outlook as they are using that

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaMail to create a multipart mime message with your To, CC, Subject and attachment.  Then instead of transporting the message call [saveChanges](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#saveChanges--) and [writeTo](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#writeTo-java.io.OutputStream-) and store the email to the file system.

There is an [undocumented](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Outlook-for-Windows-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6) `/eml` switch that can be used to open the MIME standard format.  For example, `outlook /eml filename.eml`  There is a documented `/f` switch which will open `msg` files.  For example `outlook /f filename.msg`  The [`x-unsent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527035(v=exchg.10).aspx) can be used to toggle the send button.

Here is an example to get you started:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Create message envelope.
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage((Session) null);
    msg.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse("you@foo.com"));
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("support@bar.com"));
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,
            InternetAddress.parse("manager@baz.com"));
    msg.setSubject("Hello Outlook");
    //msg.setHeader("X-Unsent", "1");

    MimeMultipart mmp = new MimeMultipart();
    MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
    body.setDisposition(MimePart.INLINE);
    body.setContent("This is the body", "text/plain");
    mmp.addBodyPart(body);

    MimeBodyPart att = new MimeBodyPart();
    att.attachFile("c:\\path to file.attachment");
    mmp.addBodyPart(att);

    msg.setContent(mmp);
    msg.saveChanges();


    File resultEmail = File.createTempFile("test", ".eml");
    try (FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(resultEmail)) {
        msg.writeTo(fs);
        fs.flush();
        fs.getFD().sync();
    }

    System.out.println(resultEmail.getCanonicalPath());

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
    pb.command("cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "outlook.exe",
            "/eml", resultEmail.getCanonicalPath());
    Process p = pb.start();
    try {
        p.waitFor();
    } finally {
        p.getErrorStream().close();
        p.getInputStream().close();
        p.getErrorStream().close();
        p.destroy();
    }
}
```

You'll have to handle clean up after the email client is closed.

You also have to think about the security implications of email messages being left on the file system.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code

Comment: Only if you promise to read the [JAVAMAIL API FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html) and keep your JavaMail up to date. Sign here:

Comment: thank you for the piece of code.But i have add more than one attachment at a time

Comment: @Thomas see it as an excercise, there are more than enough hints in the code.

Comment: it worked for me.but i need the outlook to open with send option.

Comment: set the x-unsent header to 1 and you can edit the message and sent is.
`message.setHeader("X-Unsent", "1");`