# Javax.mail or java email - how to open email without direct sending

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, javax

I'm trying to figure it out of how to open an email using javax.mail. My goal is to provide a feature where a user clicks on a button and a default email will open with an attachment. So far, I'm using javax.mail and what it does is just sending the email right when the button is click. Is there a way to just open the email without direct sending? If so, how? I'm using Java 8.

I can't use the 'mailto:' because I need to attach a png file when a user opens an email. Also I'm not sure if I should use ProcessBuilder to open outlook because every user's machine will have a different userName within the C Drive or I'm not sure how to use that.

Here's my code just in case if you need it

```
 String result;
       String to = "....gov";
       String from = "....gov";
       String host = "....gov";

       Properties properties = System.getProperties();
       properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
       Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
           try{
          MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
          message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailFrom));
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(emailTo));
          message.setSubject("meh!");

          BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
          messageBodyPart.setText("text body mehmehmehmeh");

       // Create a multipar message
             Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

             // Set text message part
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

             // Part two is attachment
             messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
             String filename = "testing.png";
             DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
             String imageString = toDataURL.substring("data:image/png;base64," .length());
             byte[] contentdata = imageString.getBytes();
             ByteArrayDataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(contentdata, "image/png");

             messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
             messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  //

             // Send the complete message parts
             message.setContent(multipart);

          Transport.send(message);
          result = "Sent message successfully....";
       }catch (MessagingException mex) {
          mex.printStackTrace();
          result = "Error: unable to send message....";
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to just open the email without direct sending? If so, how?

Don't call `Transport.send`.  Then [follow the steps in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769026/need-to-open-ms-outlook-with-attachments/36771253#36771253) and start with `msg.saveChanges()`.  There is an `X-Unsent` header in that answer that can be used to toggle some outlook features.

> Also I'm not sure if I should use ProcessBuilder to open outlook because every user's machine will have a different userName within the C Drive or I'm not sure how to use that.

You use [`File.createTempFile`​](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) as this will account for user names.  If you need to save in a different location you can read from [`System.getProperty​`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) or if you are only targeting Windows machines you can read from [System.getenv](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv-java.lang.String-).  To list all the environment vars you can type `set` in the command window.